# Fire events on Selecting date on DateTimeControl

Tags: datepicker, datetimecontrol

How to fire event when selecting date on DateTimeControl?

Answer (score 2):

Remember to set AutoPostBack to true if you want the control to react on user selection. 
This is a nice read about the [DateTimeControl](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/datetimecontrol-control/) that describes all its features.

The DateChanged event is described at MSDN:

[DateTimeControl.DateChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol.datechanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can Override the OnPickerFinish() function in DatePicker.js to fire the event when the date is updated from datepicker control

```
function OnPickerFinish(resultfield)
{
    clickDatePicker(null,"","");
    if (resultfield.id == MyDateField.id)
    {
         alert("Date changed...");
    }
}
```